# How to save chemistry equations in MySQL table field

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to save chemistry equations in my database, equations for example:

```
`AB + O2 → Oxide of A & B`
```

Even typing here `2` is coming beside `O` whereas **it's the symbol of oxygen like below**:

[image]

Please note: If I am trying to directly copy and paste it in MySQL table field using phpMyAdmin, there also `O2` is not getting saved as a symbol.

Note: MySQL field is `text` , collation is `utf8mb4_general_ci`.

Saving from php to mysql is next step. For now at least simply copying it (from phpMyAdmin) should work in MySQL.

Comment: Is there any code involved that might trigger this problem? Without any details (your question does not contain any PHP code nor any MySQL queries or the table structure), there is nearly no way to help

Comment: Not sure what is your problem. The equations use HTML syntax and UTF8 characters to format them that way. You need to save raw HTML, not text. Maybe some styles.

Comment: I want a way out to copy these equations and paste it in my mysql db using phpmyadmin and not php or any front end for now, is there any way to do it ?

Comment: Is this a programming question at all? It seems you basically want to copy web site fragments into a database using only a browser and a MySQL client. It isn't too different from trying to save YouTube videos in a pendrive using the clipboard. That isn't how computers work.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the subscript numbers on the web pages aren't actually subscripts, its just the HTML tag making it. (the `<sub>` tag).
So you have to use some kind of converter for it or do it yourself to convert it to actual unicode subscript.

If you want to print the equations to web page from database, you can save it with the HTML tag e.g.

```
H<sub>2</sub>O
```

Comment: how can i copy the equations from web page and paste it in mysql using phpmyadmin, this is my question

Comment: If you want to print the equations to web page from database, you can save it with the HTML tag e.g. `H<sub>2</sub>O`